# На что влияет внутренний указатель массива?

Tags: php

Ну кроме `foreach` до PHP 7. [Источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: на позицию текущего элемента в массиве.

Comment: он не влияет, а просто указывает на текущий элемент. и такие операторы как foreach его передвигают, или не передвигают как в пхп 7. обычно используется с функциями `next`, `prev`, 'current`, 'reset`, что само по себе не  частое являение

Comment: Я имел ввиду какими ещё операторами используется внутренний указатель? Где он ещё используется кроме foreach?

Comment: я вам вроде перечислил функции, которые его явно используют. больше наверное и нигде.

Comment: @teran Я имею ввиду помимо этих функций, разумеется.

Comment: @Hipster ну ещё со внутренним  указателем взаимодействуют mysql-функции, такие как mysql_fetch_assoc(), mysql_fetch_array(), end() ... Только что проку вам от знания этого? Может быть лучше расскажете, какую цель вы преследуете? Какую конкретно задачу вам надо решить?

Comment: Просто многие функции работающие с массивами сбрасывают этот указатель. Хотел знать где я могу наломать дров.